# Absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2n)}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I have to discuss the conditional and absolute convergence of the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$
I believe such a series is conditionally convergent but not absolutely convergent, but I lack some evidence.

Comment: Not Absolutely convergent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not absolutely convergent. It follows from the equidistribution of the sequence $\{e^{in}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $S^1$, or from the Dirichlet box principle: among three consecutive integer numbers, $\left|\sin(2n)\right|\geq\frac{1}{2}$ holds for at least one of them, hence:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{3N}\frac{|\sin(2n)|}{\sqrt{n}}\geq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3i}}\geq \sqrt{\frac{N}{3}}-\frac{1}{2}.$$
On the other hand, the series is conditionally convergent by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ decreases to zero and the partial sums of $\sin(2n)$ are bounded.

Comment: I have trouble proving that the partial sums of $sin(2n)$ are bounded.

Comment: @Antanana: search it on MSE. It has been asked before. The point is the $\sin(2n)$ is just the imaginary part of $e^{2in}$, so you end with computing the imaginary part of a geometric sum.

Comment: Good observation on the sum of the Sin(2n)! Hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to show that the series does not converge absolutely is to use

$\displaystyle\frac{\lvert \sin 2n\rvert}{\sqrt{n}}\ge\frac{\sin^2 2n}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-\cos 4n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{\cos 4n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$,

where $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{\cos 4n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ diverges

since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos 4n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges by Dirichlet's test.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute series diverges.  To see this we just need to argue that Sin(2n) isn't near 0 terribly often, which is the same as asking that 2n not be near a multiple of $\pi$ terribly often.  An ungraceful way to see that is to note that if, say, |2n - k$\pi$| < .01 then neither 2n - 2 nor 2n + 2 can be within .01 of any multiple of $\pi$ (as multiples of $\pi$ are separated by something greater than 3).  Thus deleting all the terms corresponding to  |2n - k$\pi$| < .01 means that, at worst, you are only taking out 1 term in 3.  And the surviving terms are each ≥ $\frac{sin(.01)}{\sqrt{n}}$.  The comparison now goes in the correct direction.

Note:  I did warn that this was ungraceful.  I expect it diverges conditionally as well, but do not know for certain.

Answer (score 0):

An idea: You can try [Dirichlet test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). You have that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to zero monotonically, and the only trouble is partial sums of the sine. Here the complex exponential and geometrical series may be of help.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried to use the Dirichlet test. The bigges problem I had was the sine. I couldn't bring the series of sine to a nicer form.

Comment: I will try what you have suggested.